# Python: Print string in reverse

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance

Write a program that takes in a line of text as input, and outputs that line of text in reverse. The program repeats, ending when the user enters "Done", "done", or "d" for the line of text.

Ex: If the input is:

```
Hello there
Hey
done
```

then the output is:

```
ereht olleH
yeH
```

I have already the code like this.  I don't understand what I have done wrong. Please help.

```py
word = str(input())
the_no_word = ['Done', 'done', 'd']
while word == "Done" and word == "done" and word == "d":
    break
print(word[-1::-1])
```

Comment: Your code only calls `input` and `print` once. The loop is doing nothing. Rethink that. What do you want to repeat? That is what should be inside the loop.

Comment: Think about this line: `while word == "Done" and word == "done" and word == "d":`. If it is true that `word == "Done"` then the other 2 conditions will be false because `"Done"  != "done"`. But your code with `and` specifies that all 3 conditions must be true at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did for my lab assignment in Zybooks and passed all of my tests:

```
userinput = str(input())
stop = ['Done', 'done', 'd']

while userinput not in stop:
    print(userinput[::-1])  
    userinput = str(input())
```

Make sure to add 'userinput = str(input())' at the end of the while loop so that you don't end up with an infinite loop

Comment: Why are you passing the return value from *input()* to *str()*?

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you:

```
word = ""
the_no_word = ['Done', 'done', 'd']
while word not in the_no_word:
    word = str(input())
    print(word[-1::-1])
```

You need to get the user input into `word` after every loop and check if word is **not** in the list of `the_no_word`. Let me know if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: your lines are not in the correct order, and there should be an initial word input before the loop.

Comment: Still not quite right.  It will print `enod` before exiting.  Really shouldn't give a homework answer a direct answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
while (word := input()) not in {'Done', 'done', 'd'}:
    print(word[::-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var1 = str(input())
bad_word = ['done', 'd', 'Done']
while var1 not in bad_word:
    print(var1[::-1])
    var1 = str(input())
```

Just did the problem and used this answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
word = str(input())
the_no_word = ['Done', 'done', 'd']
while word not in the_no_word:    
    print(word[::-1])
    word = str(input())
```

This should do the work.

Answer (score -1):

This should work for you!

```
word = str(input())
the_no_word = ['Done', 'done', 'd']
while word not in the_no_word:
    print(word[-1::-1])
word = str(input())
```

Comment: If the input is anything other than 'Done', 'done' or 'd' this will loop indefinitely. Also, *input()* returns type *str* so why you're passing the value to *str()* is a mystery

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

```
string = str(input())

no_words = ['Done','done','d']
while string not in no_words:
    if string in no_words:
        print()
    else:
        print(string[-1::-1])
        string = str(input())
```

Comment: Can you please format the code properly and explain what this does

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).